# Text Display Problems in Parrot OS

Tags: display, parrotsec, virtualenv

I have a dual-booted Parrot OS with Windows 11. Whenever I run a virtual environment in Parrot, like a Virtual Machine, Instance or Terminal on a browser like Firefox or Tor, I get distorted coloured vertical lines in place of text. I have also noticed this problem while working with online MATLAB. Why is this happening and is there a way to fix this?
[image: pwn college]
[image: matlab]